# Pandas Read Excel with skip merged cells

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to read xlsx file using pandas library. I want to skip rows till row 11 and then start reading, i tried skiprows options of pandas but it doesn't seems work and giving back the error `xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: ZIP file contents not a known type of workbook`
[image]

I can't able to figure out what is wrog here. here is the code for what I tried. the rows from B1:E1, B2:E2 and so on till row B10:E10 are merged rows.

```
read_conversion_raw_file = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", skiprows=10)
```

Comment: @meW still getting the same error.

Comment: `skiprows = range(10)` should work

Comment: @meW I did my research before asking the question this is applicable over errors associated in columns, my concern is not related to that, however, the error is same as in the stack question you are referring .

Comment: can you upload the file on a shared path (say google drive), from where I can test it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_rQqxcHdtDc4qQcyYyZ82n4-VdhKM91E  Here is the file.

Comment: I'm able to read it properly using your code only. The problem is something else.

Comment: I'm still not able to read and getting same error.

Comment: import pandas as pd
read_file = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", skiprows=range(11), converters={'Advertiser ID': str})
print(read_file)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185880/discussion-between-monika-rai-and-mew).

Answer (score -1):

I tried to read this file using `test.xlsx` and `test.csv` but it gives the error in both cases.
So, one possible solution is to convert this `test.xlsx` into a text file `test.txt` and then read it by skipping first 10 rows like this,

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=",", skiprows = range(10))
```

Output:

```
      Campaign                                        Site (DCM)    Placement   Date    Activity    Advertiser  Advertiser ID   Total Conversions
0   002|2018|Q1|Accounting|Accounting|LON|UK_ACGRC_ affectv.co.uk   PKMG3Y_Sage|Payroll|Sage One |UK|Display|Looka...   2018-11-28  Non-Conversion FL   Sage|UK 8205616 1
1   002|2018|Q2|Accounting|LON|UK_ACGRC_    facebook UK SAGE|Accounting|Sage_One|UK|Social|Intrests|Fa...   2018-11-28  Accounting|FY17|Q4|LP|brochure  Sage|UK 8205616 2
2   002|2018|Q2|Accounting|LON|UK_ACGRC_    facebook UK SAGE|Accounting|Sage_One|UK|Social|Intrests|Fa...   2018-11-28  HR&Payroll|FY18|Q4|LP|BOFURetargeting   Sage|UK 8205616 1
3   002|2018|Q2|Accounting|LON|UK_ACGRC_    facebook UK Sage|Accounting|SageOne|UK|Social|WebsiteRTG|F...   2018-11-12  Non-Conversion FL   Sage|UK 8205616 2
4   002|2018|Q2|CoreFinancials|LON|UK_CRFG_ facebook UK SAGE|Core Financials|Sage Live|UK|Social|Looka...   2018-11-14  Non-Conversion FL   Sage|UK 8205616 2
```

Output format is bit confusing due to space but hopefully it fulfills your question requirements.

Comment: its not working as i said the cells are merged for B:E from row 1 to row 10

Comment: can you upload your dataset file so I can go through that.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_rQqxcHdtDc4qQcyYyZ82n4-VdhKM91E  Here is the file

Comment: @MonikaRai I have updated the reply. Please have a look on it. Thanks for patience.

Comment: I believe this is a not a permanent solution i'm looking for.

Comment: @MonikaRai data in the excel file is not in correct format that's why it's giving error either I try to read it as an xlsx or csv file. Converting excel to text file is not a big deal and that solves your problem as well. Still if you want xlsx or csv file, you can easily write Dataframe to either xlsx or csv file and that will be the permanent solution. You can use that file in future without any data further problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185885/discussion-between-abdur-rehman-and-monika-rai).